# jenkins-as-code: purpose of jobs

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, continuous-delivery

I want to use Jenkins and store the configuration and the pipeline in my SCM(e.g. git). To do so, I created a directory, let's say "jobs" in the root of my project where I will store jobs.groovy files written as JobDSL plugin files.

Should I do all the things in a single job file, like fetching the source code, testing it, maybe building Docker images if necessary, then deploying on AWS cloud? Or for each operation, should I create different jobs? If so, then how can I create a pipeline using these job files?

Answer (score 0):

look at jenkins configuration as code plugin. following link would be helpful
https://github.com/tomasbjerre/jenkins-configuration-as-code-sandbox